# HTML Entities Displaying Encoded when Cloned with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

I'm new to jQuery, and while my code does mostly what I want it to (in duplicating a form group), I'm having a couple of issues with the classes/values of the buttons:

1. When clicked, the .btnadd that is appended to the .formdupgroup loses it's value, rather than having a '+' symbol on it, it displays nothing.

2.When the duplicate .btnadd classes are changed to be .btnremove, they display the HTML entity as text on the button. Rather than a 'x' symbol, they read '×' in full.

I'm sure these issues are related to decoding the HTML entities in both cases, but I can't find a way to work around it, without resorting to just typing the unevenly spaced 'x' and '+' characters. How do I add a decoded HTML entity as the value on my inputs?

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.btnadd',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $(this).parents('.formdupgroup:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.toduplicate:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

            newEntry.find('input').val('');
            newEntry.find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            controlForm.find('.btnadd:not(:last)')
                .removeClass('btnadd').addClass('btnremove')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .val('&times;');
    }).on('click','.btnremove', function(e){
        $(this).parents('.toduplicate:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container-fluid'>
        <form>
            <div class='formdupgroup'>
                <div class='form-row toduplicate'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group col-md-8'>
                        <label for='selectexample' class='sr-only'>Select Example</label>
                        <select name='selectexample' class='form-control'>
                            <option value='' disabled selected>Please Select an Option</option>
                            <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
                            <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
                            <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
                            <option value='4'>Option 4</option>
                            <option value='5'>Option 5</option>
                            <option value='6'>Option 6</option>
                            <option value='7'>Option 7</option>
                            <option value='8'>Option 8</option>
                            <option value='9'>Option 9</option>
                            <option value='10'>Option 10</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                        <input type='button' class='btn btn-success btnadd' value='&plus;'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape + and × so you can just enter these directly into your function.

The reason the value is blank is because the `val` property is being reset by this line:

```
newEntry.find('input').val('');
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9yz6gcn4/1/)

Comment: Thanks very much @user7290573 , that's a massive help.

Comment: @user7290573 and i worked so hard on my model to make it work with the html characters. it has been a nice challange tho.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `.val('&times;');` Doesnt put an "x" in there is because javascript does not parse these html codes itself. You will need to specify that it has to be parsed.

Here is a working model to use html codes in javascript/jquery.

```js
$(function(){
 var parser = new DOMParser;
    $(document).on('click','.btnadd',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $(this).parents('.formdupgroup:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.toduplicate:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

            newEntry.find('input').val(parser.parseFromString('&plus;', 'text/html').body.textContent);
            newEntry.find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            controlForm.find('.btnadd:not(:last)')
                .removeClass('btnadd').addClass('btnremove')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .val(parser.parseFromString('&times;', 'text/html').body.textContent);
    }).on('click','.btnremove', function(e){
        $(this).parents('.toduplicate:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container-fluid'>
        <form>
            <div class='formdupgroup'>
                <div class='form-row toduplicate'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group col-md-8'>
                        <label for='selectexample' class='sr-only'>Select Example</label>
                        <select name='selectexample' class='form-control'>
                            <option value='' disabled selected>Please Select an Option</option>
                            <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
                            <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
                            <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
                            <option value='4'>Option 4</option>
                            <option value='5'>Option 5</option>
                            <option value='6'>Option 6</option>
                            <option value='7'>Option 7</option>
                            <option value='8'>Option 8</option>
                            <option value='9'>Option 9</option>
                            <option value='10'>Option 10</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                        <input type='button' class='btn btn-success btnadd' value='&plus;'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This also works for html codes that dont apear on your keyboard. for example `&spades;`